# Is creating a custom model the way to access data in a table by name?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Say I have a QTableWidget with 10 columns. I set data in the table with

```
  QTableWidgetItem* textItem1 = new QTableWidgetItem;
  textItem1->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, 20);
  this->tableWidget->setItem(row, col, textItem1);
```

The problem is that if I change the order or titles of the columns in the table using QtDesigner, I have to go through my code and change all of the column numbers. I would rather do something like this:

```
  QTableWidgetItem* textItem1 = new QTableWidgetItem;
  textItem1->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, "Smith");
  this->tableWidget->setLastName(row, textItem1);
```

to add "Smith" to the "LastName" column, without needing to know which column index LastName currently is. Is the way to do this with a custom Model? I looked into [QAbstractTableModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstracttablemodel.html), but I don't understand how to provide named access to data? Can anyone briefly explain how one would do this? And if this is a reasonable/common thing to want to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted an example of using QAbstractTableModel:

http://programmingexamples.net/index.php?title=Qt/ModelView/QAbstractTableModel

As you can see, the data is simply stored in a member variable, and can therefore be accessed however you would like.